# MySQL Update with Select statement from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table called time_table with the following columns

```
--------------------------
 time_table
--------------------------
col_name | type
id       | int
user_time| datetime
```

This table has record in it. When I updated the table to :

```
--------------------------
 time_table
--------------------------
col_name | type
id       | int
user_time| datetime
utc_time | datetime
```

I want to Select all the user_time column, get its UTC equivalent and Update the utc_time column in one query.

I tried this query but it didn't work.

```
UPDATE time_table p1, ( 
SELECT id, CONVERT_TZ(user_time,'+00:00','+05:00') AS newtime
FROM time_table sp WHERE sp.id=p1.id) AS p2
SET p1.utc_time = p2.newtime
WHERE p1.id = p2.id
```

I know there is something wrong with my query but I don't know what's wrong with it. Any suggestions? It would be a great help.

Comment: why are you joining? there is no need to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to join

```
UPDATE time_table 
SET utc_time = CONVERT_TZ(user_time, '+00:00','+05:00')
```